# Simple aura if statement question

Tags: aura

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation), this is how you should write it:

`<aura:if isTrue="{proposal.status === 'draft'}">`

But when deploying I get:

> isTrue="{proposal.status === 'draft'}" is not valid attribute for aura:if. All attributes name should be all lowercase.

So when making `isTrue` lowercase I get this instead:

> Ambiguous attribute value istrue="{proposal.status === 'draft'}". If you want to make it a valid identifier you should remove the surrounding quotes istrue={proposal.status === 'draft'}. If you want to make it a string you should escape it istrue="{proposal.status === 'draft'}"

So I remove the double quotes and then I get this:

> Invalid HTML syntax: unexpected-equals-sign-before-attribute-name. For more information, please visit https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-unexpected-equals-sign-before-attribute-name

I've also tried creating another boolean field called `isDraft`:

`<aura:if istrue={proposal.isDraft}>`

That deploys fine but always returns true regardless if `isDraft` is false or not.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm doing this if statement within a loop: `<template for:each={proposals} for:item="proposal">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/get-started-component-library.html), not [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_components.htm). These are two different technologies. You're looking for [`lwc:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html), not `aura:if`.

```
<template lwc:if={proposal.isDraft}>
 ...
</template>
```

Unlike Aura, expressions are not supported, so you do have to create a new property (as you did). Do not use quotes for these kinds of attributes. Do not use `{!...}` syntax, but instead `{...}`. Only lowercase letters, underscores, and hyphens are allowed for attribute names.

Comment: I am using `<aura:set` though, maybe I shouldn't be doing that

Comment: @dan-klasson Correct. See the documentation from the link above; you would use lwc:else for the alternative condition.

Comment: I'm using it for this `<aura:set attribute="title" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-m-left_x-small">`

Comment: @dan-klasson Anything starting with `aura` is not meant for LWC. Instead, it's `<header slot="title" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-m-left_x-small">`

Answer (score 0):

If `proposal` is an attribute, you need to reference it with `v.` in front. You also need to prefix with `!` (unlike in LWC). E.g.:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.proposal.isDraft}">
```

Comment: The `!` is part of the expression syntax for aura, and is tied to the opening curly brace, not the `v`.

Comment: It still complains about the `isTrue` not being lowercase. Does not work with double quotes either. Without it, it gives me `[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'proposal')]`

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Are you doing an Aura component or a Lightning Web Component?